# Visual Studio can compile project, but in cli, msbuild shows MSB4019 error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to compile [this project](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz) with Visual Studio 2017.

In Visual Studio it compiles with a few warnings. But when I open cmd and build it with `msbuild`, it fails with `MSB4019` error:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

That's weird, am I using the wrong command line parameter?

Comment: It seems that it was the VS2010 project, can you compile it in VS2010? In addition, you'd better to check that which platform or configuration your project uses during you open them using the VS IDE. It is hard for us to make sure that it has no updated/merge issue if you use the VS2017 to open the old VS version project.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT It compiles fine within the UI, but fails in command line, so it's a msbuild parameter issue

Comment: Do you make sure that all projects were loaded successfully in your VS2017? In addition, MSB4019 error would be related to the mimidrv project's loaded, you could view the output windows->Build or Solution, view the detailed output messages, not all error messages were in the Error list window, you would check the detailed output window in your VS IDE.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks, the error message is not clear enough ... But it does seem to be mimidrv's problem. I've changed the command to `msbuild /target:mimikatz:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 /p:PlatformToolset=v141` and it worked :-) Going to delete this question once you read this message.

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, if possible, please don't delete this case, you could share a solution as an answer, so you could mark it answer, and it could help other community members who get the same issue, anyway, glad to know that it works well now. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message from msbuild is not clear enough. But as `Jack Zhai-MSFT` pointed out, it might be related to mimidrv.

So simply ignore mimidrv and build only mimikatz target solved this problem, e.g

```
msbuild /target:mimikatz:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 /p:PlatformToolset=v141
```